# Declare a flexible math operator (such as expectation operator)

Tags: math-operators, subscripts

I would like to define a math operator, such as the expectation operator, which will be able to optionally receive subscript and/or superscript.

Currently what I have is

```
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left(#1\right)}
```

and I call it with `\E{X}`. This is nice, but when I wish to add a subscript I fall to `\mathbb{E}_x\left(X\right)` and it's quite annoying.

I therefore defined another command:

```
\newcommand{\Ex}[2]{\mathbb{E}_{#1}\left(#2\right)}
```

but that's not really helpful for two reasons: (a) I need to remember two commands, and (b) the usage is not intuitive (I use it with `\E{x}{X}` instead of something like `\E_x{X}`.

Can I define a math operator whose usage will be either of the following:

- `\E{X}`
- `\E_x{X}`
- `\E^2{X}`

and whose output in each case would be

- `\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)`
- `\mathbb{E}_x\left(X\right)`
- `\mathbb{E}^2\left(X\right)`

It this possible?

Note that **`DeclareMathOperator*`** is not good for the task, as in display mode it puts the sub/superscripts below/above the operator.

Comment: Have you considered using `\DeclareMathOperator` (without the asterisk)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementation for `\E`, which has optional sub- or superscripts before the mandatory argument. It uses `\mleft` and `\mright` to avoid additional horizontal spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\E}{%
  \def\E@sub{}%
  \def\E@sup{}%
  \E@scripts
}
\newcommand*{\E@scripts}{%
  \@ifnextchar_\E@subscript{%
    \@ifnextchar^\E@supscript\E@finish
  }%
}
\def\E@subscript_#1{%
  \ifx\E@sub\@empty
    \def\E@sub{#1}%
  \else
    \errmessage{E already has a subscript}%
  \fi
  \E@scripts
}
\def\E@supscript^#1{%
  \ifx\E@sup\@empty
    \def\E@sup{#1}%
  \else
    \errmessage{E already has a superscript}%
  \fi
  \E@scripts
}
\newcommand*{\E@finish}[1]{%
  \mathbb{E}%
  \ifx\E@sub\@empty\else _{\E@sub}\fi
  \ifx\E@sup\@empty\else ^{\E@sup}\fi
  \mleft(#1\mright)%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[ \E{X}, \E_x{X}, \E^2{X}, \E_x^2{X}, \E^2_x{X} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting such a long implementation for such a common task... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't make the macro `\E` take an explicit argument. Instead, I would define `\E` via a `\DeclareMathOperator` statement and then write `\E(X)`, `\E X`, etc. That way, you can decide "on the fly" whether or not to use parentheses.

Note that this approach requires no extra typing during input: You simply replace `\E{X}` with `\E(X)` -- exact same number of characters. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\begin{document}
$\E(K)$, $\E_x(K)$, $\E^2(K)$, $\E_x^2(K)$

\medskip
$\E K$, $\E_x K$, $\E^2 K$, $\E_x^2 K$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I would argue that this is actually even more flexible than what the OP wanted. And it its implementation is much, much easier (though less interesting from a TeXnical point of view `;-)`). What one loses though is the ability to change the brackets after the expectation globally (there seem to be people who prefer `\E(X)` and some that prefer `\E[X]`).

Comment: Thanks for another point of view! However, I tend to use `\left(`... or rather `\mleft(`... and I never use these operators without parenthesis. So Heiko's answer is more appropriate in my case (even though the implementation is really crazy).